# Can we use class as an dependency injection instead of interface

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I've used another class as Dependency Injection is it good to work around or I've messed up the OOP way.

**Helper.php**

```
class Helper {

    public function getModulePermission($role_id, $module, $type) {
        // my work code
    }

}
```

**DesignationController.php**

```
use App\Helpers\Helper;

class DesignationController extends Controller {

    protected $designation;
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * @param DesignationContract $designation
     * @param Helper $helper
     */
    public function __construct(DesignationContract $designation, Helper $helper) {
        $this->designation = $designation;
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $permission = $this->helper->getModulePermission($request->id, 'Designation', 'view');      
        if ($permission) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return view('errors.forbidden');
        }
    }
```

So I've a class named `Helper` which can be accessed within each and every controller for checking permissions but I thought that I've messed up the OOP functionality over here. Is it good to work like it as or I need to create an `Interface` instead of class

Comment: The DI looks good to me. However, you might want to look at php coding standards : http://www.php-fig.org/psr/ . You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

- Those are two different OOP concepts. the interface forces whoever class implement it to implement functions stated in the interface (called function signature). So for multiple classes implement the same interface, you will end up with multiple classes implement the same set of functions (wither it is the same function body or not).
- The second concept is called, dependency injection or inversion of control in some cases. you inject a class either via class constructor or via setters and you call certain function provided by the injected class. Here you will have the same function called by multiple classes which is good for less modification by using common (injected) class, easier unit-testing (you can mock objects easily), more modular code (you can inject different class if you want different functionality).

So the current situation is good enough but it all depends in what you want to do  which stated above.

Comment: Wrong. `DI !== IoC`. DI is a way to achieve IoC.

Comment: No it is not wrong! "In software engineering, dependency injection is a software design pattern that implements inversion of control for resolving dependencies." see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection for more :)

Comment: Exactly, learn to read your wiki articles :) IoC is a principle, one of the SOLID ones. DI is a technique or a pattern, which help you achieve it.

Comment: Well, IoC and DI are both patterns. DI is a specialization of IoC which means DI inherits IoC with some slight changes that makes it somehow different. and as you may know, in inheritance, the sub-class is the same type of parent class.

Comment: @AngelIliikov IoC is not a principle, but an implementation and it has nothing to do with SOLID. From wiki  *The term is related, but different from the dependency inversion principle*

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the name, it speaks nothing to me or gives me an idea that this class can help me get the permissions of the module. Moreover, with a name like this, one can simply put another method, like lets say `Helper::login($id)` or you name it, which will instantly break the single responsibility principle (laravel controllers do that anyway).

The injection is relatively OK, perhaps a middleware class would be better place to do that.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to change that name into `PermissionHelper` but can you provide an example of middleware over here

Comment: Here is the laravel doc: http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware, I think its pretty much self explanatory.